# Getting the title of a link, AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm sort of stuck on this.

I have a XMLHttpRequest object which is connected to some link, and I can get the responseXML from it. Now, how would I get the value of the `<title>` tag, from the responseXML?

I found a way to do it with a regex, but, its very ugly, and I would rather not use it (it uses responseText).

I also cannot use jQuery, Prototype, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an XML response the property xhr.responseXML holds the XML document, so use the DOM API

```
var titleElement = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
var titleText = titleElement.textContent
```

In order to make it more cross-browser use

```
var titleElement = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
var titleText = titleElement.textContent // DOM Level 3 compatible browsers
    || titleElement.innerText // IE
    || (titleElement.firstChild && titleElement.firstChild.nodeValue) // other
    || '';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should have noticed this by myself.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more details, so the code is more cross-browser. In that code I assume that title tag has only one child that is a text node.